# Case statement for class objects

Tags: ruby, class

If I have `klass` that may (or may not) be an instance of `Class`, how can I check `klass` against given classes in case-statement style to see which class it is a subclass of?

For example, suppose `klass` happens to be `Fixnum`. When I check `klass` against `Integer`, `Float`, ..., I want it to match `Integer`. This code:

```
case klass
when Integer ...
when Float ...
else ...
end
```

will not work because it will check whether `klass` is an **instance** of the classes. I want to check whether `klass` is a **subclass** of the classes (or is itself that class).

This is the best I can do so far, but I feel it may be an overkill and is not efficient:

```
class ClassMatcher
  def initialize klass; @klass = klass end
  def === other; other.kind_of?(Class) and other <= @klass end
end

class Class
  def matcher; ClassMatcher.new(self) end
end

klass = Fixnum
case klass
when Integer.matcher then puts "It is a subclass of Integer."
when Float.matcher then puts "It is a subclass of Float."
end
# => It is a subclass of Integer.
```

Comment: Why not just check if `obj.ancestors.include? Integer`, etc?

Comment: @ChrisHeald Why not replace all (conventional) case statements with `obj.kind_of?(foo)`, etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Ruby's case statement uses ===, and the behavior of === in regards to class comparisons is pretty well documented. If it won't do what you want in this case, then use something that will.

Comment: @ChrisHeald I don't think you understand the question at all.

Comment: Perhaps you've failed to explain it properly, then. As I read it, you're expecting invalid behavior from `case`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald I never wrote I want to use `case` statement itself. That is your misinterpretation. I wrote I want to do it in case-statement style.

Comment: Would checking `klass.class.ancestors.include?` for each of the specific cases (`Integer`, `Float`,...) be what you're looking for?

Comment: @pjs No. It would not.

Comment: @sawa what is wrong with pjs's ancesor?

Comment: When `klass` is `Fixnum`, `klass.class` is `Class`. It will not match against `Integer` because `Class`'s ancestors do not include `Integer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something more functional?

```
is_descendant = lambda { |sample, main| main <= sample }
not_a_class = lambda { |x| !x.kind_of?(Class) }

mine = Fixnum

case mine
when not_a_class then raise 'Not a class' # Credits to @brymck
when is_descendant.curry[Float] then puts 'Float'
when is_descendant.curry[Integer] then puts 'Integer'
else raise 'Shit happens!'
end

# ⇒ Integer
```

Comment: This is the second answer after davogones' that is close to answering what I asked. This will work, except that it will raise an error in case `mine` happens not to be a class.

Comment: @sawa Aside from filtering out non-classes before the case statement, you could add another lambda like `not_a_class = lambda { |x| !x.kind_of?(Class) }` and put `when not_a_class ...` at the top of the case statement.

Comment: @brymck That is a good idea.

Comment: Lambdas, nice! Forgot you could use those.

Answer (score 3):

```
case 
when klass <= Integer ...
when klass <= Float ...
else ...
end
```

Repetitive, but probably the only way to do what you're looking for.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that is close to answering what I want, and it is actually close to what I have so far. But note that I wrote `klass` may not be an instance of `Class`. Your code raises an error in such case.

Comment: That's not a use case of case statements then.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) and [`Module#<=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-3C-3D) ?

```
obj = Fixnum
[Float, Integer].find { |cls| obj.kind_of?(Class) && obj <= cls }
# => Integer
```

or simple `if`, `elsif`, ..:

```
obj = Fixnum
if ! obj.kind_of? Class; puts 'It is not a class'
elsif obj <= Integer; puts 'It is a subclass of Integer'
elsif obj <= Float; puts 'It is a subclass of Float'
else; puts 'other'
end
# => It is a subclass of Integer
```

Comment: I don't want the matching class to be returned. I want to write a condition based on it.

Comment: You could use this statement as the case condition.

Comment: @falsetru How can I do that?

Comment: @sawa, `case [Float, Integer].find { |cls| Fixnum < cls }.to_s  ; when 'Integer' .....`

Comment: @falsetru That may work, but it is not clean code.

Comment: @sawa, Alternatively you can build a hash that maps class to proc.

Comment: @falsetru: But that's messy when you're checking for `<=` rather than just `==` on the classes.

Comment: @muistooshort, What do you mean **that**? If you mean *hash* suggestion, I meant using the hash with `[Float, Integer].find { |cls| Fixnum <= cls }`.

Comment: @falsetru You would probably know if you actually try to implement that.

Comment: @sawa, [I tried to implement it](http://ideone.com/px6pCG). I still don't know. Please explain me.

Comment: I thought you were talking about a hash with class keys and lambda values. I'm still not sure what sawa is trying to do here (besides probably trying to be overly clever when something simple and straight forward would be sufficient).

Comment: @muistooshort, Thank you for comment. I agree with you.

Comment: @muistooshort Do you have suggestions for something simple and straightforward?

Comment: @falsetru I was thinking something similar to muistooshort. I got what you mean. But your answer as is in incomplete.

Comment: @sawa: If you had of explained yourself clearly then I would have ended up with something like mudasobwa's. But you ended up revealing important bits and pieces in various comments all over the place. If you had of started off with a clear and complete question then there wouldn't be any arguing or comment threads to muddy the waters.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually it will:

```
case Class
when Module
  puts 'Class is a subclass of Module'
end
```

Edit:

Only that comes to my mind after your explanations:

```
case
when Fixnum < Integer
  puts 'Fixnum < Integer'
end
```

Comment: This is correct. `case` uses ===, which is equivalent to a `kind_of?` check, rather than an `instance_of?` check.

Comment: It does not work when `obj` is anything other than `Class`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald It does not matter which it is. Either will not work.

Comment: @sawa Ah, are you wanting to check if the Fixnum class is a subclass of Integer (as opposed to an instance of Fixnum)?

Comment: Updated the answer. That's the only way I can think of using case statements.